# Volunteer Work to get exposure to UX

Tags: experience

I wanted to see what would be the best way to look for volunteer work so that I can get some exposure to UX. I want to know where designers such as yourself started looking for side project to get experience?

Comment: I'm not sure it's the same question, but take a look at this question about [free UX training opportunities](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56336/any-free-ux-trainig-opportunities/56338#56338)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is the type of question more suited to a general UX discussion forum like Quora, or as a chat topic in the UXSE chatroom rather than a question specific to UX design problems.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at participating in hackathons. This may seem like a developer focus thing, but most projects they work on usually have a user facing component associated to it and thus can use the skill of UX designers. Most developers would love to get a designer to help make their stuff look polished.

I would start by going to http://www.meetup.com and search for hackathon events happening in your area.

Comment: Yeah or go to Eventbrite. You can find a number of hackathons happening at major metropolitan areas - NYC, Boston, Philadelphia, San Fran, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Offer your services to non profits.

Comment: This *can* be a good option, but a few caveats: 1) Typically UX can not work alone, so it's not always an easy thing to pitch by itself. 2) remember that non-profit isn't synonymous with "doesn't have money to pay". :)

Comment: Agree with what DA01 said, I would never recommend working for free unless you absolutely have to and have exhausted all other options. You work and time, no matter how unskilled, is worth more than nothing. I'd stay away from people who want to give you just "things to put in your portfolio" and so on.

Comment: I wouldn't consider non-profit work to be 'for free'. If your goal is to get experience, then the implication is that you have none. If you have no experience in an area, then it's reasonable that you shouldn't expect to be paid.

Comment: @MelHogan the guy mowing my lawn may not have experience doing it, but I'm pretty sure he expects me to pay him.

Comment: @DA01 I think we can agree to disagree on this one. I have my point of view, and you have yours. No worries.

Comment: @MelHogan Whether you and I agree or not isn't a big deal, but I do want to emphasize for others that they don't need to work for free to gain experience. Even internships can (should) be paid positions--yes, there are a few industries where that isn't the norm (Television, being one) but those tend to be the exceptions rather than the rule.

Comment: @DA01 I agree people shouldn't work for free, but the context of this question was gaining experience, which sometimes you can get easier access to if it's not necessarily income based. And technically, if you're getting an education, it's not necessarily working for free. That said, if you have a skill set that is worthy of pay, then yes, you can find work for hire. If however you're simply seeking to learn, and an individual or company is willing to help you do so, there is a cost in time for that entity, whether they pay you in cash or not. Not all compensation is monetary.